# Firebase-Auth throws FirebaseNetworkException on University Network

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase for authentication of users for my Android app. The same authentication code (`signInWithEmailAndPassword`) works when I run it at home using Android emulator, but when I go to the University, a `FirebaseNetworkException` is thrown.

Log:

```
01-18 11:03:08.755 23073-23073/com.app.name W/SignIn: signInWithEmail:failed
com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException:
A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbix.zzcb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbiu$zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbjf.zzcc(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbjf$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbja$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

Is it possible this is due to the university restricting access to a port? Does anyone know the port number used by Firebase Authentication? Anyone know how this can be fixed?

Comment: Hi mimi, try to use `FirebaseNetworkException` methods like `getCause() `. Write a try/catch to see it. Like this: `try { Log.d("TAG", "Great, it works!"); } cath (FirebaseNetworkException e) { Log.d("TAG", "Problems: "+ e.getMessage());}`  Read more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseNetworkException